# How do i create SMTP credentials for wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I don't Know about SMTP mail server.I need this credentials for my wordpress website to get form data.Anyone could explain this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress wants to use an SMTP mail server to send email. Since you don't have one, you could use Google's mail server ([have a look here on how to](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/blastex/
And send emails without local smtp server :)

```
< ?php
!!! Enable first in php.ini config file socket extension. Read more in plugin admin panel after activation !!!

$to = 'hello@emal.com, hello@boom.com';
$subject 'Hello from email client';
$html = 'Hello message from smtp !!!

Message from wordpress plugin!

';

// Install and activate plugin and send emails
$ok = wp_mail($to, $subject, $html);

// Show error
echo get_option('blastex_error');

?>
```